# Jacoco code coverage setup

Tags: jacoco

I wanted to get the code coverage in my project basically my project is deployed on a websphere server where in I have added -javaagent argument in the jvm of the server and the exec file is generated in the destfile parameter and the same I use to get the code coverage from sonar.
The problem I am facing is I get issues in my code when I add the -javaagent argument in the jvm of the server whereas whenever I remove this argument my application runs perfectly.

Can I get the complete procedure to get the code coverage in sonar for my project.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What exact command did you run? What exact issues (error messages) did you get?

Comment: The exact argument in jvm is -javaagent:<path to the jacocoagent.jar>=destfile=<path where I want jacoco to create exec file>,append=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was due to use of reflection in my project jacoco interferes with these implementation and so null pointer is thrown from my applications code so now the plan is to use a check for isSynthetic for reflection usages.